# Remove border from line in Tikz

Tags: tikz-styles, tikz-arrows, plot

I'm using Tikz to draw some diagrams.

However, when i use `\draw [shift={(232.14,97)}, rotate = 90] [fill={rgb, 255:red, 115; green, 201; blue, 255 }  ,fill opacity=1 ][line width=0.01]  [draw opacity=0] (4.8,-1.2) -- (0,0) -- (4.8,1.2) -- cycle    ;` there is still a black line around the object:

[image]
How can i solve this?

Whole code:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.75pt,y=0.75pt,yscale=-1,xscale=1]
%uncomment if require: \path (0,300); %set diagram left start at 0, and has height of 300

%Straight Lines [id:da22349387736428006] 
\draw  [dash pattern={on 0.84pt off 2.51pt}]  (260,130) -- (232,110.6) ;
%Straight Lines [id:da29311458312574956] 
\draw  [dash pattern={on 0.84pt off 2.51pt}]  (139.14,115.82) -- (120,120) ;
%Straight Lines [id:da05623331520653507] 
\draw    (139.14,114.82) -- (180,131.17) -- (231,110.33) ;
%Shape: Circle [id:dp7665677720333088] 
\draw  [fill={rgb, 255:red, 128; green, 128; blue, 128 }  ,fill opacity=1 ][dash pattern={on 3.75pt off 3pt on 7.5pt off 1.5pt}] (135.64,115.82) .. controls (135.64,113.89) and (137.2,112.32) .. (139.14,112.32) .. controls (141.07,112.32) and (142.64,113.89) .. (142.64,115.82) .. controls (142.64,117.75) and (141.07,119.32) .. (139.14,119.32) .. controls (137.2,119.32) and (135.64,117.75) .. (135.64,115.82) -- cycle ;
%Shape: Circle [id:dp193113222269232] 
\draw  [fill={rgb, 255:red, 128; green, 128; blue, 128 }  ,fill opacity=1 ][dash pattern={on 3.75pt off 3pt on 7.5pt off 1.5pt}] (176.5,130.17) .. controls (176.5,128.23) and (178.07,126.67) .. (180,126.67) .. controls (181.93,126.67) and (183.5,128.23) .. (183.5,130.17) .. controls (183.5,132.1) and (181.93,133.67) .. (180,133.67) .. controls (178.07,133.67) and (176.5,132.1) .. (176.5,130.17) -- cycle ;
%Shape: Circle [id:dp9306623067288149] 
\draw  [fill={rgb, 255:red, 128; green, 128; blue, 128 }  ,fill opacity=1 ][dash pattern={on 3.75pt off 3pt on 7.5pt off 1.5pt}] (228.5,110.6) .. controls (228.5,108.66) and (230.07,107.1) .. (232,107.1) .. controls (233.93,107.1) and (235.5,108.66) .. (235.5,110.6) .. controls (235.5,112.53) and (233.93,114.1) .. (232,114.1) .. controls (230.07,114.1) and (228.5,112.53) .. (228.5,110.6) -- cycle ;
%Shape: Circle [id:dp08269290559401243] 
\draw  [fill={rgb, 255:red, 184; green, 233; blue, 134 }  ,fill opacity=1 ][dash pattern={on 3.75pt off 3pt on 7.5pt off 1.5pt}] (136.35,94.82) .. controls (136.35,92.89) and (137.92,91.32) .. (139.85,91.32) .. controls (141.79,91.32) and (143.35,92.89) .. (143.35,94.82) .. controls (143.35,96.75) and (141.79,98.32) .. (139.85,98.32) .. controls (137.92,98.32) and (136.35,96.75) .. (136.35,94.82) -- cycle ;
%Shape: Circle [id:dp6993402699496214] 
\draw  [fill={rgb, 255:red, 184; green, 233; blue, 134 }  ,fill opacity=1 ][dash pattern={on 3.75pt off 3pt on 7.5pt off 1.5pt}] (176.5,150.31) .. controls (176.5,148.38) and (178.07,146.81) .. (180,146.81) .. controls (181.93,146.81) and (183.5,148.38) .. (183.5,150.31) .. controls (183.5,152.24) and (181.93,153.81) .. (180,153.81) .. controls (178.07,153.81) and (176.5,152.24) .. (176.5,150.31) -- cycle ;
%Shape: Circle [id:dp6125576427238653] 
\draw  [fill={rgb, 255:red, 184; green, 233; blue, 134 }  ,fill opacity=1 ][dash pattern={on 3.75pt off 3pt on 7.5pt off 1.5pt}] (228.5,91.17) .. controls (228.5,89.23) and (230.07,87.67) .. (232,87.67) .. controls (233.93,87.67) and (235.5,89.23) .. (235.5,91.17) .. controls (235.5,93.1) and (233.93,94.67) .. (232,94.67) .. controls (230.07,94.67) and (228.5,93.1) .. (228.5,91.17) -- cycle ;
%Straight Lines [id:da0822256545819966] 
\draw [color={rgb, 255:red, 115; green, 201; blue, 255 }  ,draw opacity=1 ]   (180.43,136.71) -- (180.43,143.29) ;
\draw [shift={(180.43,145.29)}, rotate = 270] [fill={rgb, 255:red, 115; green, 201; blue, 255 }  ,fill opacity=1 ][line width=0.08]  [draw opacity=0] (4.8,-1.2) -- (0,0) -- (4.8,1.2) -- cycle    ;
%Straight Lines [id:da7978560807556065] 
\draw [color={rgb, 255:red, 115; green, 201; blue, 255 }  ,draw opacity=1 ][fill={rgb, 255:red, 115; green, 201; blue, 255 }  ,fill opacity=1 ]   (140,103.43) -- (140,107.48) -- (140,110) ;
\draw [shift={(140,101.43)}, rotate = 90] [fill={rgb, 255:red, 115; green, 201; blue, 255 }  ,fill opacity=1 ][line width=0.08]  [draw opacity=0] (4.8,-1.2) -- (0,0) -- (4.8,1.2) -- cycle    ;
%Straight Lines [id:da5331445738451293] 
\draw [color={rgb, 255:red, 115; green, 201; blue, 255 }  ,draw opacity=1 ]   (232.14,99) -- (232.14,105.57) ;
\draw [shift={(232.14,97)}, rotate = 90] [fill={rgb, 255:red, 115; green, 201; blue, 255 }  ,fill opacity=1 ][line width=0.01]  [draw opacity=0] (4.8,-1.2) -- (0,0) -- (4.8,1.2) -- cycle    ;
%Straight Lines [id:da6900959224002201] 
\draw [color={rgb, 255:red, 0; green, 0; blue, 0 }  ,draw opacity=1 ]   (177.78,122.54) -- (172.14,109.86) ;
\draw [shift={(179,125.29)}, rotate = 246.04] [fill={rgb, 255:red, 0; green, 0; blue, 0 }  ,fill opacity=1 ][line width=0.08]  [draw opacity=0] (3.57,-1.72) -- (0,0) -- (3.57,1.72) -- cycle    ;
%Straight Lines [id:da593624024668693] 
\draw [color={rgb, 255:red, 0; green, 0; blue, 0 }  ,draw opacity=1 ]   (188.44,147.19) -- (199.86,140.43) ;
\draw [shift={(185.86,148.71)}, rotate = 329.38] [fill={rgb, 255:red, 0; green, 0; blue, 0 }  ,fill opacity=1 ][line width=0.08]  [draw opacity=0] (3.57,-1.72) -- (0,0) -- (3.57,1.72) -- cycle    ;
%Straight Lines [id:da12254190749709593] 
\draw    (113,160) -- (277,160) ;
\draw [shift={(280,160)}, rotate = 180] [fill={rgb, 255:red, 0; green, 0; blue, 0 }  ][line width=0.08]  [draw opacity=0] (3.57,-1.72) -- (0,0) -- (3.57,1.72) -- cycle    ;
\draw [shift={(110,160)}, rotate = 0] [fill={rgb, 255:red, 0; green, 0; blue, 0 }  ][line width=0.08]  [draw opacity=0] (3.57,-1.72) -- (0,0) -- (3.57,1.72) -- cycle    ;
%Straight Lines [id:da007746876971784333] 
\draw    (140,156) -- (140,160) ;
%Straight Lines [id:da3974779179972072] 
\draw    (180,156) -- (180,160) ;
%Straight Lines [id:da555126001881239] 
\draw    (230,156) -- (230,160) ;

% Text Node
\draw (151.43,92.94) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]  [font=\tiny,color={rgb, 255:red, 128; green, 128; blue, 128 }  ,opacity=1 ] [align=left] {$\displaystyle \mathcal{N}\left( \theta _{t} |\mu _{t}^{-} ,\ \mathbf{C}_{t}^{-}\right)$};
% Text Node
\draw (200.57,130.94) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]  [font=\tiny,color={rgb, 255:red, 128; green, 128; blue, 128 }  ,opacity=1 ] [align=left] {$\displaystyle \mathcal{N}\left( \theta _{t} |\mu _{t}^{+} ,\ \mathbf{C}_{t}^{+}\right)$};
% Text Node
\draw (116,100.8) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]  [font=\tiny,color={rgb, 255:red, 115; green, 201; blue, 255 }  ,opacity=1 ] [align=left] {$\displaystyle y_{t-1}$};
% Text Node
\draw (166.57,135.8) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]  [font=\tiny,color={rgb, 255:red, 115; green, 201; blue, 255 }  ,opacity=1 ] [align=left] {$\displaystyle y_{t}$};
% Text Node
\draw (238,96.8) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]  [font=\tiny,color={rgb, 255:red, 115; green, 201; blue, 255 }  ,opacity=1 ] [align=left] {$\displaystyle y_{t+1}$};
% Text Node
\draw (131,161.8) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]  [font=\tiny] [align=left] {$\displaystyle t-1$};
% Text Node
\draw (177,161.8) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]  [font=\tiny] [align=left] {$\displaystyle t$};
% Text Node
\draw (221,161.8) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]  [font=\tiny] [align=left] {$\displaystyle t+1$};
% Text Node
\draw (128,71.8) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]   [align=left] {{\tiny smoothing $\leftarrow$ filtering $\rightarrow$ prediction}};

\end{tikzpicture}
```

Edit: I took a liberty and add image produced by your code snippet.

This is what I get:
[image]
[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Are you sure you attached to complete code? I ran my code and it only drew a blue triangle facing down without a black border.

Comment: edited to whole code

Comment: i use mathcha.io to generate this code

Comment: The diagram is small but even when zooming in 400X, I still cannot see the black lines. Can you please compile the code again and post a complete picture of the output?

Comment: I took a liberty and add image generated by your code fragment. Please, explain now, what ob this image you not liked or drawing wrong. In drawing your image I use recent version of Ti*k*Z package.

Comment: strange..i did compiled it again, ad added the whole graph. Still got these black lines

Comment: i'm just importing \usepackage{tikz}

Comment: I don't think you can change opacity midway in a draw statement (but I have to check that). Why you use that command and not a Ti*k*Z native arrow?

Answer (score 1):

I guess, that you looking for something like this:

[image]

Similar result (I show it in your question) I get when I insert your code snippet in my MWE instead of my image code. So, it is not clear, why you get different result. Anyway, you should instead of code fragment provide complete small document (MWE: Minimal Working Example), which reproduce your result.

However, your code sniped is terrible. The *mathcha.io*  utility (according to my opinion, but here are users of it who disagree with me) mostly generate garbage of code (or you not use it adequate) ... For serious work you should at least elementary learn Ti*k*Z and coding `tikzpicture` directly in your LaTeX editor. Doing so, your problem cannot happen. For example as:

```
\documentclass[border=3.141592]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                positioning,
                quotes}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
               > = {Triangle[scale=0.8]},
      arr/.style = {-{Triangle[length=2.4mm, width=1mm]}, color=cyan,
                    shorten >=1mm, shorten <=1mm},
        C/.style = {circle, draw, dashed, fill=#1, inner sep=2pt},
        N/.style = {inner sep=2pt, font=\scriptsize},
every pin/.style = {pin distance=5mm, 
                    pin edge={<-,shorten <=1pt, draw=black}, 
                    inner sep=1pt, font=\scriptsize, text=gray}
                    ]
% x-axis
\draw[<->]  (-4,0) -- (4,0);
\foreach \i [count=\x from -1, count=\j] in {$t-1$, $t$, $t+1$}
    \draw (3*\x,0.1) -- ++ (0,-0.2) node (n\j) [N, below] {\i};
% gray circles
\node (g1) [C=gray, above=24 mm of n1] {};
\node (g2) [C=gray, above=15 mm of n2,
            pin={90:$\mathcal{N}\left(\theta_{t}\vert\mu_{t}^{-},\mathbf{C}_{t}^{-}\right)$}] {};
\node (g3) [C=gray, above=24 mm of n3] {};
    \draw(g1) -- (g2) -- (g3);
% green circles
\node (c1) [C=green, above=7 mm of g1] {};
\node (c2) [C=green, below=7 mm of g2,
            pin={0:$\mathcal{N}\left(\theta_{t}\vert\mu_{t}^{+},\mathbf{C}_{t}^{+}\right)$}] {};
\node (c3) [C=green, above=7 mm of g3] {};
% cyan arrows
\draw[arr] (g1) to [N, "$y(t-1)$"] (c1);
\draw[arr] (g2) to [N, "$y(t)$"]   (c2);
\draw[arr] (g3) to [N, "$y(t+1)$"] (c3);
% legend
\node [above=22mm of g2]  {smoothing $\leftarrow$ filtering $\rightarrow$ prediction};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I agree with you: the wysiwyg utility is generating a code that is not streamlined nor logical. If you want a black box picture, the OP would be much safer in generating a PDF and including it.